# Getting 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis', cannot find error

Tags: sql, oracle

After running my script in Oracle I am getting the error code 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis'. I have already created the client and employee tables, both of which ran correctly and added the tables alright. However I am getting an issue creating my 'Appointment' table. The code for creating it is below:

```
create table Appointment
(appointment_num number(9) not null primary key,
appointment_time datetime(),
emp_ID number(4) not null references employee (emp_ID),
client_ID number(9) not null references client (client_ID))
```

Cannot find where the error is and cannot find any troubleshooting guidance elsewhere for the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `datetime()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have `datetime()`, change it to `date`. Please note that `datetime` is invalid datatype on oracle, you need to use `date` or alternatively `timestamp`

```
create table Appointment
(
  appointment_num number(9) not null primary key,
  appointment_time date,
  emp_ID number(4) not null references employee (emp_ID),
  client_ID number(9) not null references client (client_ID)
)
```

---

Diference between `Date` and `Timestamp`

> One of the main problems with the DATE datatype was its' inability to be granular enough to determine which event might have happened first in relation to another event. Oracle has expanded on the DATE datatype and has given us the TIMESTAMP datatype which stores all the information that the DATE datatype stores, but also includes fractional seconds.

[Reference](https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_date_time.html)

Comment: When I change it to that I get the error 'ORA-00902: invalid datatype'.

Comment: I am sorry It must be date rather than datetime :)

Comment: So that works fine! I need to have a time for each appointment as well, what is the data type for Time in SQL? I have tried 'time' but I run into more errors.

Comment: date is fine, you can use it for time as well.

Comment: Date also contains the time.

Comment: And If you believe that this answer is usefull, please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer so that community can also benefit from it :) thanks

Comment: @G.Hines: Oracle doesn't support separate `DATE`, `TIME` and `DATETIME` types. They only have `DATE` which actually is a datetime; it contains both a date and a time. Thus midnight either represents, well, midnight, or no time at all (`2018-01-24` = `2018-01-24 00:00:00`). (And they have `TIMESTAMP` for datetimes with fractions of seconds and optional timezones.)